# Conditional vue component show

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm building a generic table component on **VUE**, and pass by `props` the reference source.

Example:

```
<drk-table table="users"></drk-table>
```

After this, I use the `Axios` to load the data from my server in the `mounted()` event.

This works fine when I have **only one component in my template**.

---

But if I try to reuse the component with **different props** in a conditional **v-if**, only the first table its load:

```
<div v-if="currentPage == 0">
    <drk-table table="users"></drk-table>
</div>
<div v-else-if="currentPage == 1">
    <drk-table table="admins"></drk-table>
</div>

*(currentPage is a data field)*
```

---

However if I do the same with **v-show** it's works:

```
<div v-show="currentPage == 0">
    <drk-table table="users"></drk-table>
</div>
<div v-show="currentPage == 1">
    <drk-table table="admins"></drk-table>
</div>
```

---

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-app-bar app clipped-left color="amber">
        </v-app-bar>

         <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app clipped color="grey lighten-4">
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-content>
            <v-container fluid fill-height>
                <v-layout align-center justify-center>
                    <v-flex text-xs-center>
                        <div v-if="currentPage == 0">
                             <drk-table table="users"></drk-table>
                        </div>
                        <div v-else-if="currentPage == 1">
                            <drk-table table="admins"></drk-table>
                        </div>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-content>
        <v-footer color="indigo" app>
        </v-footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        drawer: false,
        itens: [
            { icon: 'contacts', text: 'item0' },
            { icon: 'settings', text: 'item1' },
        ],
        currentPage : 0,

    }),

    methods:{
        goPage(item){
            console.log("goint to "+item);
            this.currentPage = item;
        }
    }

};
</script>
```

The official documentation from `VUE` says that the `v-if` will recreate the item every time who the condition turns TRUE.

My doubt about this is why the `v-if` doesn't work properly when I use the same component with different props?

In this case, I need to change my `mounted()` event?

Comment: `<div v-show="v-else-if == 1">`? Perhaps you mean `<div v-else-if="currentPage === 1">`.

Comment: A typo, sorry. adjusted

Comment: Can you show how `currentPage` is modified and defined?

Comment: Ok, I updated with the full code

Comment: You should't have both a prop and state with the same name (currentPage).

Comment: currentPage it's only my data variable, not my props.
If I put a <h1> tag in each condition, this will be show properly.
However, my custom element with props doesn't work with v-if, but work with v-show.